# Calling function from Google Chrome Console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to manually call a function from Google Chrome Console, but its saying that

"Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"

My code is as follows:

```
var ScatterGame = new Class({
    Binds: "mStart mEnd mDrop mEnter mLeave touchHandler instructionStart".split(" "),
    gameOver: function() {
        clearInterval(this.secondTimer);
    }

}),
```

I'm trying to put in `ScatterGame.gameOver()`, but its throwing that error. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: where does "Class" come from? and wouldn't you call the gameOver methods from the instance, not as a static of the constructor?

Comment: Yes, in the code it is called from the instance, but I want to manually call it in the GC console.

Comment: i don't know where your _Class_ function puts the method, but typically, you can use prototype to reach a method without an instance, as in Array.prototype.slice.call("abc", 1)

Comment: Alright, I think that worked, but now Google Chrome is saying this: function (){if(c.$protected&&null==this.$caller)throw Error('The method "'+b+'" cannot be called.');

Comment: sounds like something your _Class_, but again, i have no idea what _Class_ is. it should give you a line number if it's coming from your script. if you want to do this kinda of stuff, i would not fight against the Class tool you're using and instead just implement vanilla OOP JS, it's not that bad...